# How to send a JavaScript object on the server side (ASP NET MVC)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-web-api

Below is the relevant code (JS+jQuery on the client side):

```
function getuser(username, password) {
    var user = new Object();
    user.constructor();
    user.username = username;
    user.password = password;
    //....
    $("#a1").click(function () {
        var u = getuser($("#username").val(), $("#password").val());
        if (u == false) {
            alert("error");
        } else {
            //....
        }
    });
}
```

The question is how to send  `var u` to a session on the server side?

Comment: If you want to pass it as entire object try to serialize object using JSON.stringify(), and then deserialize it on server side. Before that create an object with same fields on server side. If you want to send parameters separately use simple ajax call and pass parameters in data: { username: username, password: password. }

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to accomplish this. Something like:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "/Controller/Action/",
      data: {
        u: u
      },
      cache: false,
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "html",
      success: function (data) {
        //handle response from server
      }
    });
```

Then have a controller action to receive the data:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Action(string u)
    {
      try
      {
        //do work
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        //handle exceptions
      }
    }
```

Note that `/controller/action` will be specific to where youre posting the data to in your project

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)
For example: 
If you just want to do a simple post the following may suit your needs:

```
var user = getUser(username, password);
$.post(yourserverurl, user, function(response){console.log("iam a response from the server")});
```

As the documentation says:

> This is a shorthand to the equivalent Ajax function:

```
    $.ajax({
  type: "POST", 
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

So In your example:

```
      $.ajax({
  type: "POST", 
  url: "/mycontroller/myaction",
  data: {user: getUser(username, password)},
  success: function(responseFromServer){//handleResponseHere},
  error: function(xhr){//handleyourerrorsHere}
  dataType: yourdatatype
});
```

Comment: In this example I need to use in get method.

Comment: Just switch post with get then